# 3 CCMenuItemToggle that need to be "ON" each one at a time?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

using cocos2d CCMenus .

i have 3 `CCMenuItemToggle` which are under the same ccmenu .

Now, i want that if the user press one of them,he toggle to ON , **BUT** if then he choose another

```
CCMenuItemToggle
```

the previous item is toggle back(OFF) and the new one becomes ON .

how would i do that ??

thanks lot .

Comment: anyone? its marked as answered but i dont see any answer here..

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually trigger the toggle in the callback from the CCMenuItemToggle. In case this triggers yet another callback you would have to also add a lock to your code so that it doesn't actually run that untoggle code as that is probably not what you want.

I have asked the same question and also answered it myself here:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17826

Regards!